# Is there a firebug style utility for Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Does anyone know if there is a Firebug style tool for use in Internet Explorer?

### Edit

I've ben using IE8. So ideally, I would like the solution to work with IE8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try Firebug Lite: http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Install

And also IE Developer Toolbar for IE version 7 and below.

Comment: There is no IE Developer Toolbar for IE8 and above? Really?

Comment: I imagine that was a typo, and should have been >8

Comment: IE 8 has built-in Developer Tools. "The Developer Toolbar is not compatible with Internet Explorer 8. Please use the developer tools included with Internet Explorer 8.  Press F12 or click the 'Developer Tools' entry in the Tools menu to begin using the tool." http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535#SystemRequirements

Comment: Use the built in tools.  Press F12.

Answer (score 4):

[Firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) ?

Answer (score 1):

There is [IE Web Developer Toolbar](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/article.php/3733341/Must-Have-Internet-Explorer-Web-Developer-Toolbar.htm) for that.

[image]

Or you can go for [Firebug light](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) that works in all browsers.